# Post Pagination in WordPress Child Theme - every page link displays the same posts

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I am doing a WordPress site.  I created a child theme and have written/pasted in some code.  Much of it works and is standard code.  But the part about the Pagination is really hard for me.  I have tried all day and I can't get it to work.  I am really stuck.  The Page Links under the list of Posts all return the same Posts, no matter which page number you click on, instead of showing the newest posts on the first page and older posts on the second page.

[List of Posts - Navigation Always Shows The Same Posts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fZLS.png)

Here is the code

```
<?php

//  Template Name: blog home         /

//  Jason Damisch's Category File    /

 ?>


<?php get_header(); ?>



<!--                  CONTENT                   -->
<!--                                            -->

<?php
   wp_reset_query();                     // necessary to reset query
   while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
      the_content();
   endwhile;                             // End of the loop.
?>


<BR>
<HR>
<BR>

<!--                  POSTS                    -->
<!--                                           -->

<DIV STYLE="font-size:20px;">AHA HAPPENINGS</DIV>
<BR>

<?php
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'category_name' => 'Not Board Minutes',
        'posts_per_page' => 8,
        'paged' => $paged
    ) );
?>


<?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>

<!-- begin loop -->
<?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

    <DIV STYLE="font-size:18px; color:#6EC1E4 !important;"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Read"><?php the_title(); ?></a></DIV>

<!--    <?php  the_excerpt(); ?>   -->

<?php  foreach (get_the_category() as $category){   ?>
<?php  echo $category->cat_name;                    ?>
              &nbsp;   &nbsp;
<?php   }                                           ?>

    <BR>
    <?php echo get_the_date(); ?>

    <DIV STYLE="height:10px;"></DIV>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<!-- end loop -->




<!--             PAGINATION                    -->
<!--                                           -->

<div class="pagination">
    Pages of Happenings<BR>
    <?php
        echo paginate_links( array(
            'base'                => get_pagenum_link() . '%_%',
            'total'               => $query->max_num_pages,
            'current'             => max( 0, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
            'format'              => '?paged=%#%',
            'show_all'            => false,
            'type'                => 'plain',
            'end_size'            => 2,
            'mid_size'            => 10,
            'prev_next'           => true,
            'prev_text'           => __(' - Previous - '),
            'next_text'           => __(' - Next - '),
            'add_args'            => false,
            'add_fragment'        => '',
            'before_page_number'  =>  '<FONT SIZE=+2> &nbsp;&nbsp;[',
            'after_page_number'   =>  ']&nbsp;&nbsp; </FONT>',
        ) );
    ?>
</div>



<?php else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>



<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Can somebody please help me out and tell me what I am doing wrong.

I expected each of the page links to show different posts depending upon how old the posts are.

I tried to create a child theme, and then my template for the child theme.  Then I put my code in the template php file.  I tried this code in three different child themes, two for Elementor and one for Gutenberg.  And they all behave the same.  So, it seems to be my fault.  I have tried several plugins to display posts but either they didn't do anything or I had to pay for the features I needed.  I Googled all day long to try to find the solution.  This is the second day and its going rough for me.  I Hope that somebody can help.

Jason

Answer (score 0):

Issues are facing maybe because of base URL
Please update these things in your paginate_links() function and try

```
'base'                => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
'total'               => $query->max_num_pages,
'current'             => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
'format'              => '?paged=%#%',
```